# How do I keep the download count of a url in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, logging

More precisely can I configure Nginx to output the log entry to a separate log file whenever a particular url is requested? Later the number of lines in that log can give me the download count.

**nginx.conf**

```
error_log  /home/webadmin/applegrew.com/error-n.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1000;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    index         index.html index.htm index.php index.shtml;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout 5; 

    gzip  on;

    server {
        server_name cink.applegrew.com;

        access_log /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/access.log main;
        error_log  /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/error.log;

        root /var/www/cink.applegrew.com/html;

        location = /js/cink\.compiler\.min\.js$ {
            access_log /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/download-compiler-min.log main;
        }
        location = /js/cink\.renderer\.min\.js$ {
            access_log /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/download-renderer-min.log main;
        }
        location = /js/cink\.combined\.min\.js$ {
            access_log /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/download-combined-min.log main;
        }
        location /js/src/ { #This works
            access_log /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/download-src.log main;
        }

        include cacheCommon.conf;
    }

}
```

**cacheCommon.conf**

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|txt|xml)$ {
    # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please post the full configuration file?

Another way is use `grep -c`:

```
grep -c "/js/cink.renderer.min.js" /path/to/the/main/access_log
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
location = /js/cink\.renderer\.min\.js$ {
            access_log /var/log/cink.applegrew.com/download-renderer-min.log main;
        }
```

1. Remove all the backslashs before the dot.
2. Either remove the `$` at the end or use `~` instead of `=`. `$` means
   the end of line in RegEx, so you must use the `~` prefix.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but I would prefer keeping individual logs. This is just a personal preference.

Comment: Please show us the entire of configuration file. Do you mean the log file is blank when you said "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes the logs files are created but remain blank.

Comment: How we can help without config file?

Comment: Provided now. :-)

Comment: Please check out my above answer.

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I used `location = /js/cink.renderer.min.js`

Comment: be aware that if you ever call that file with a query string it probably wont log to that file...

Answer (score 2):

this probably would work in your nginx vhost for the site

```
location ~* /path/to/file.ext$ {
    access_log /var/log/some/seperate.log;
}
```

where the /path/to/file.ext is relative to your webroot

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have url of the form - `http://cink.applegrew.com/js/cink.renderer.min.js`. For this I tired with `/js/cink.renderer.min.js`. I also tried escaping the `.`. It works if I give `/js/`, but I want to log one specific file.

Comment: see Iain's answer, the location tag needs tweaking, i've corrected mine on that basis - the root tag isnt strictly required and make sure this appears above any other rules (eg above where you include cacheCommon.conf)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
location ~* /js/cink.renderer.min.js$ {
        root /var/www/cink.applegrew.com/html;
        access_log /path/to/separate/log/file;
    }
```